# binary-to-text encoding that replace a byte into a predefined unique string in golang

Tags: go, encoding, byte, decoding

I am trying to build a binary-to-text encoder with the ability to replace every byte into a predefined unique string and then use the same string set to decode back into binary.

I am able to make the encoder and decoder for simple .txt files but I want to make this workable for .zip files too.

Encoder :

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    // keys.json is a 256 words dictionary for every byte
    keysFile, err := os.Open("keys.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("unable to read keys.json file , error : %v", err)
        return
    }

    var keys []string

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(keysFile)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &keys); err != nil {
        log.Printf("unable to unmarshal array , error : %v", err)
        return
    }

    Encoder(keys)

}

func listFiles(file *zip.File) ([]byte, error) {
    fileToRead, err := file.Open()
    if err != nil {
        msg := "Failed to open zip %s for reading: %s"
        return nil, fmt.Errorf(msg, file.Name, err)
    }
    b := make([]byte, file.FileInfo().Size())
    fileToRead.Read(b)

    defer fileToRead.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to read zip file : %s for reading , error : %s", file.Name, err)
    }

    return b, nil
}

func Encoder(keys []string) {
    read, err := zip.OpenReader("some.zip")
    if err != nil {
        msg := "Failed to open: %s"
        log.Fatalf(msg, err)
    }
    defer read.Close()

    var encodedBytes []byte
    f, err := os.Create("result.txt")
    w := bufio.NewWriter(f)

    defer f.Close()
    for _, file := range read.File {
        readBytes, err := listFiles(file)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to read %s from zip: %s", file.Name, err)
            continue
        }

        for i, b := range readBytes {

            for _, eb := range []byte(keys[b] + " ") {
                encodedBytes = append(encodedBytes, eb)
            }

        }

    }
    _, err = w.Write(encodedBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error :%v", err)
        return
    }
}
```

Decoder :

```
    func Decoder(keys []string) {
    inputFile, err := os.Open("result.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("unable to read file , error : %v", err)
        return
    }

    inputBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(inputFile)

    var (
        current []byte
        decoded []byte
    )

    for _, c := range inputBytes {
        if c != 32 {
            current = append(current, c)
        } else {

            for i, key := range keys {
                if string(current) == key {
                    decoded = append(decoded, byte(i))
                    break
                }
            }
            current = []byte{}
        }
    }

    // here i want the decoded back into zip file
}
```

[here](https://github.com/44kia244/lorem-encode) is a similar one in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You are dealing with spaces correctly, but not with newlines.
- Your decoder loop is wrong. As far as I can tell, it should look like the following:

```
for i, key := range keys {
   if string(current)==key {
     decoded=append(decoded,i)
     break
   }
}
```

Also, your `decoded` is an int-array, not a byte-array.

Comment: yes you'r right and now the problem is that I need to produce .zip file from that int-array again, what's your thoughts about this?

Comment: Make decoded a []byte, and use decoded=append(decoded,byte(i)). You can write that []byte as a zip file. BTW, what you're doing can be done with encoding.base64.

Comment: as you know there could be multiple files in .zip file while encoding but when I write []byte into .zip file while decoding, it generates only one file in .zip file while I want exactly the same files

Comment: BTW, it would be very helpful if you could share the encoding.base64 method

Comment: You are decoding all files into a single byte array. There is no delineation between files. You have to fix your decoder to figure out file boundaries. For base64 encoding look at the encoding/base64 package, it is a standart library package. It is a common and standard way of encoding binary data as text.